# Keep user authorize between restarting with SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Is there possible to keep user authorize between restarting of pool with my Asp.net MVC site? I'm using SimpleMembershipProvider for authorizing and this is how I log in:

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe);
```

But event if RememberMe is true my authorization can't stay alive after restarting of pool on my hosting provider side.

Comment: Set an explicit machinekey in your web.config.

Comment: @spender, it's work! Thank you